# Form is submitting even if validation fails

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Below is a code of a simple html form and javascript code for checking if the fields are empty or not, when user clicks the submit button.

The problem is, that the form is submitted, even if the necessary fields are not filled in.
As you can see, I am just a beginner with JS coding, so I don't know, if the problem is in if/else statements, somewhere else in the JS code or if the form is not set up properly.

```
<script>
    function preveri(pov){
        var preveriime = pov.ime.value;
        var preverirojstvo = pov.rojstvo.value;
        var preverimail = pov.email.value;
        var preverikategorijo = pov.kategorija.value;

        if (preveriime == "") {
            document.getElementById('imeA').style.display="block";                                            
        }                                    
        if (preverirojstvo == "") {
            document.getElementById('datumA').style.display="block";
        }   
        if (preverimail == "") {
            document.getElementById('emailA').style.display="block";
        }   
        if (preverikategorijo == "") {
            document.getElementById('kategorijaA').style.display="block";
        }   

        if(preveriime != "" && preverirojstvo != "" && preverimail != "" && preverikategorijo != ""){                                                                              
            document.pov.submit();
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>  

<h4>OBRAZEC ZA SPLETNE PRIJAVE</h4>
<br/>
<form name="pov" method="POST" action="thankUPage.php">
    <input name="ime" type="text" placeholder="Ime in Priimek"></input>
    <input name="rojstvo" type="text" placeholder="Datum rojstva"></input>
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-pošta"></input>
    <input name="kategorija" type="text" placeholder="Kategorija"></input>
    <textarea name="povprasaj" placeholder="Povprašaj"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Pošlji!"  onclick="preveri(pov)" />
</form>
<div id="imeA" class="imeA">Obvezno polje!</div>
<div id="datumA" class="datumA">Obvezno polje!</div>
<div id="emailA" class="emailA">Obvezno polje!</div>
<div id="kategorijaA" class="kategorijaA">Obvezno polje!</div>
</div>
```

Tnx in advance!

Comment: `onclick="return preveri(this)"` perhaps?

Comment: What if you press enter in a form field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're returning false on the click event. You need to bind your callback function to the form's submit event, so returning false will cancel the form's submission.

Pressing "enter" while in a form field will submit the form and might not trigger the click event on the submit button.

```
<form name="pov" method="POST" action="thankUPage.php" onsubmit="return preveri(this);" >
```

Comment: I just added return here:  'onclick="return preveri(this)"' and it works as it should. Is there any reason to use your method instead?

Comment: Yes : try pressing "enter" while focusing a form input. This might not trigger the click event on the submit button on some browsers. But it will trigger the form's submission.