# Form submitting without validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm working on a programming assignment for my Javascript course. We are required to create a simple form that incorporates validation rules. I'm having a lot of trouble with the actual validation, as it doesn't seem to be working when I access the elements by their IDs. The form should not be submitting and error messages are supposed to be displayed if validation fails, but for some reason I can't get it to work.

I have searched through other posts related to this topic:
[Post 1,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646471/stopping-form-submit-if-the-validation-fails)
[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597116/form-is-submitting-even-if-validation-fails?rq=1)
... But I still can't seem to get it working.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

External: [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gonocaludu/edit?html)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sam H - Assignment 2</title>
    <script>

    function focus() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
    firstName.focus();
    }

    function validation() {
        var errors = "";
        var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
        var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var confirmEmail = document.getElementById("confirmEmail").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var birthday = document.getElementById("birthday").value;
        var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
        var city = document.getElementById("city").value;



        if(firstName == "") {

        errors = errors + "Please enter your first name. ";
        }


        if(lastName = "") {

        errors = errors + "Please enter your last name. ";

        }


        if(email = "") {

        errors = errors + "Please enter your email. ";

        }

        if(confirmEmail == "") {

        errors = errors + "Please confirm your email. ";

        }

        if(password == "") {

        errors = errors + "Please enter your password. ";

        }

        if(birthday == "") {

        errors = errors + "Please enter your birthday. ";

        }

        if (email != confirmEmail) {

        errors = errors + "Emails do not match. ";
        }

        var cityLength = city.length;
        if (cityLength > 12) {
        errors = errors + "Your city length must be less than 12 characters. ";
        }



        if (errors.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("errortitle").innerHTML = "Errors:";
        document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = " " + errors;
        return false;
        } else {
        return true;
        }
    }


        /*if (firstName.value = "" ||
            lastName.value = "" ||
            email.value = "" ||
            confirmEmail.value = "" ||
            password.value = "") {

        alert("Please fill all required fields.");

        return false;

        } */
        </script> 
</head>

<body onload="focus()">


    <form name="form1" method="POST" onsubmit="return validation();">
    <p>*First Name:</p>
    <input type="text" name="first" id="firstName">

    <p>*Last Name:</p>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" name="last">

    <p>*Email:</p>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">

    <p>*Confirm Email:</p>
    <input type="text" id="confirmEmail" name="confirm">

    <p>*Password:</p>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="pass">

    <p>*Birthday:</p>
    <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birth">

    <p>Nickname:</p> 
    <input type="text" id="nickname" name="nick">

    <p>Gender:</p>
    <select name="genders" id="genderList">
    <option value="female">Female</option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    </select>

    <p>Country</p> 
    <input type="text" id="country" name="userCountry"> 

    <p>City:</p>
    <input type="text" id="city" name="userCity">

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" action="return validation();">

    </form>

    <h1 id="errortitle"></h1>
    <p id="errors"></p>



</body>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide your example through a plunkr: https://plnkr.co/

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @matyas Please don't advise people to post their code to external sites as those links may become invalid in the future. Having all the code here, is always the best approach.

Comment: You have to run the validate function on submit.

Comment: Please clean up your code. Your HTML is invalid. `<input>` elements don't get closing tags. Also, indent your code for readability. This will help you and others troubleshoot your code when it's needed (like right now).

Comment: You also might want to learn how to use your browser's built-in web developer tools. The console shows you what part of the JavaScript fails.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excess } at the end of the code. The id of the lastName field is set to "last" which causes it to not find it. Also your variables contain the value of the fields, not the fields themselves, so the focus method is not defined for them. The city field is addressed incorrectly.

Input tags also do not have a closing tag, but that is simply ignored by most browsers.

If you fix the above errors, the code will work.

```
<script>

function focus() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
    firstName.focus();
}

function validation() {
    var errors = "";
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
    var lastName = document.getElementById("last");
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var confirmEmail = document.getElementById("confirmEmail");
    var password = document.getElementById("password");
    var birthday = document.getElementById("birthday");
    var country = document.getElementById("country");
    var city = document.getElementById("city");

    if (firstName.value == "") {
        firstName.focus();
        errors = errors + "Please enter your first name. ";
    }

    if (lastName.value = "") {
        lastName.focus();
        errors = errors + "Please enter your last name. ";
    }

    if (email.value = "") {
        email.focus();
        errors = errors + "Please enter your email. ";
    }

    if (confirmEmail.value == "") {
        confirmEmail.focus();
        errors = errors + "Please confirm your email. ";
    }

    if (password.value == "") {
        password.focus();
        errors = errors + "Please enter your password. ";
    }

    if (birthday.value == "") {
        birthday.focus();
        errors = errors + "Please enter your birthday. ";
    }

    if (email.value != confirmEmail.value) {
        email.focus();
        errors = errors + "Emails do not match. ";
    }

    var cityLength = document.getElementById('city').value.length;
    if (cityLength > 12) {
        errors = errors + "Your city length must be less than 12 characters. ";
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("errortitle").innerHTML = "Errors:";
        document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = " " + errors;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

 </script>
```

Comment: Fixed errors mentioned, validation still ineffective & form submits without values.

Comment: Nevermind, glazed over a small syntax error. +1, thanks